# Having trouble running Phantomjs + node on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs

I've successfully got Phantomjs to work on Heroku but now I'm hitting issues with the phantomjs-node interface for node.js (see https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node).

When I'm attempting to initialize Phantom I'm seeing a 10-15 second delay and then:

```
> phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: socket

phantom stdout:   phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
```

You can reproduce the problem with the following steps or by pulling down my test app at https://github.com/matellis/phantom-test

```
git init phantom-test
cd phantom-test
heroku apps:create
# create node app as per Heroku instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs
# copy bin and lib folders from http://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.6.1-linux-x86_64-dynamic.tar.bz2 into root of your new project
# if you don't do this step you'll get an error "phantom stderr: execvp(): No such file or directory"
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git push heroku
```

Test your app has come up, the third to last line will tell you the URL, it should read like:

```
http://fathomless-ravine-5563.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

If successful you should see Hello World! in your browser.

Now from the same folder as your Heroku application run:

```
heroku run node
```

At the node prompt try the following:

```
phantom = require('phantom');
x = phantom.create();
```

Wait 10-15 seconds and you should see the error. Nothing works from this point on.

This should output file `foo.png`:

```
x = phantom.create(function(ph){ph.createPage(function(page){ page.open('http://bbcnews.com', function(status){ page.render('foo.png', function(result) {ph.exit()}); }); }); });
```

To validate Phantomjs is working fine on Heroku, try the following using my test project:

```
>heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.1
~ $ phantomjs test.js http://bbcnews.com foo.png
~ $ ls *.png
foo.png
```

I cannot reproduce any of these problems locally but there are other issues reported where folks may have hit this issue locally.

The problem seems to originate in `shim.js` line 1637:

```
s.on('request', function(req) {
  var evil;
  evil = "function(){socket.emit('message', " + (JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(req))) + " + '\\n');}";
  return controlPage.evaluate(evil);
});
```

I've tried variations of versions of node, phantom, etc. with no luck.

I've also tried a custom buildpack that sets the DYLD variable, see http://github.com/tecnh/heroku-buildpack-nodejs with no luck either.

Anyone who has got Phantom + Node playing together nicely on Heroku please let me know. There are several references to this on Stackoverflow but nobody is saying "I got it to work, here's how".

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm also attempting to get phantomjs and nodejs playing nice on heroku: http://goo.gl/oIhPU

Comment: do you have phantomjs compiled for Heroku?

Comment: Heroku seems to recommend this buildpack for phantom.js apps: https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs - it's also been more recently updated than the on you reference. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the phantomjs node module, but I do have an app running both node and phantomjs on Heroku.

You need to use custom buildpacks in order to get this to work. My [`.buildpacks` file](https://github.com/jessefulton/webpages-for-humans/blob/master/.buildpacks) looks like

```
http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

You should then be able to run phantomjs scripts in a child process:

```
var script = app.get('root') + '/scripts/rasterize.js' //the phantomjs script to run
  , bin = app.get('phantom') //normally this would just be the string "phantomjs"
  , spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// set up args to the phantom cli
// (run the phantomjs command in your terminal to see options/format)
var args = [];
// ...

var phntm = spawn(bin, args);

phntm.stdout.on('data', function (data) { /* do something */ });
phntm.stderr.on('data', function (data) { /* do something */ });
phntm.on('exit', function (code) { /* handle exit */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not support WebSockets. With Socket.io it has a [workaround](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku).  Not sure about `dnode`, which `phantomjs-node` uses.

I had a problem with WebSockets on Heroku too and I switched to [Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/), which solved it for me.